# python api request, service key Is not registered

Tags: python, api

The first time I deal with APIs.

The variable named : key corresponds to the authentication key.

The authentication key is not really that value.

I linked the site below.

This is the authentication key issued by the public agency.

Could you please tell me how I got the code wrong?

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen
from urllib import urlencode, quote_plus

key='anzxIHbtJcwtftW%2BRdGwUw%3D%3D'
url = 'http://apis.data.go.kr/B551182/hospInfoService/getHospBasisList'
queryParams = '?' + urlencode({ quote_plus('ServiceKey') : key, quote_plus('ServiceKey') : '-', quote_plus('pageNo') : '1', quote_plus('numOfRows') : '10', quote_plus('sidoCd') : '110000', quote_plus('sgguCd') : '110019', quote_plus('emdongNm') : '신내동', quote_plus('yadmNm') : '서울의료원', quote_plus('zipCd') : '2010', quote_plus('clCd') : '11', quote_plus('dgsbjtCd') : '01', quote_plus('xPos') : '127.09854004628151', quote_plus('yPos') : '37.6132113197367', quote_plus('radius') : '3000' })

request = Request(url + queryParams)
request.get_method = lambda: 'GET'
response_body = urlopen(request).read().decode('utf8')
print(response_body)
```

And I got the error like below

SERVICE_KEY_IS_NOT_REGISTERED_ERROR

Comment: Are there escaped character sequences in your key? Like %2B and/or %3D%3D? These would correspond to + and == which would make your key properly base64 encoded

Comment: Yeah, `urlencode()` already handles escaping, so if you're passing an escaped string in, it's going to be double-escaped.